# Разница между inline и static переменной

Tags: c++

В 17 стандарте есть новая фича: `inline` переменные. Но я не совсем понимаю, а в чем разница между `inline` и `static` переменной?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

До С++17 было два основных способа объявить/определить глобальную переменную, которая используется в нескольких единицах трансляции:

```
//my.h
extern int foo;
static int bar = 0;

//my.cpp
int foo = 0;
```

- Переменная `foo` — обычная переменная со внешним связыванием, объявлена в хедере и обределена/инициализирутся точно в одной единице трансляции.
- Переменная `bar` — статическая переменная, объявлена и инициализируется в хедере. При этом каждая единица трансляции работает со своей копией объекта. Зачастую это ошибка.

В c++17 достаточно сделать:

```
//my.h
inline int baz = 0;
```

По большей части это просто синтаксический сахар: `baz`, объявлена и инициализируется в хедере, как и в случае `static`, но все единицы трансляции работают с одним и тем же объектом, как в случае с `extern`, а компилятор сам выберет модуль, куда пристроит символ (по аналогии с `inline`-функциями).​ Оптимизационного потенциала это несёт крайне мало т.к. почти все его перспективные применения уже покрыты `constexpr​`.

Comment: Хм.. Что-то у вас двоих ответы противоположные. Можно какое-то подтверждение?

Comment: @Qwertiy, вообще одно и тоже, только у AnT'а в строгих терминах, а у меня более плебейско-практическая версия...

Comment: Неа, он говорит _"существует как отдельная переменная в каждой единице трансляции ... inline никак не меняет этих свойств",_ а ты утверждаешь, что inline создаст одну переменную для всех единиц трансляции, т. е. прямо противоположное утверждение. Ну или я я не понял, кто что имел в виду.

Comment: @Qwertiy, нет, подразумевается, что `inline` **без** `static` «существует в единственном экземпляре во всей программе», а `inline static` — «существует как отдельная переменная…», как и при отсутствии `inline`; но второе, как он замечает далее, «является избыточным».

Comment: Т. е. `inline` без `static` позволяет объявлять и инициализировать единственную для всех единиц трансляции переменную прямо в h-фале, который будет подключаться к различным cpp-файлам? Я правильно понял?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да... ЗЫ: странное чувство, когда хочется ответить просто «да», но движок SO говорит, что слишком мало символов и ты начинаешь думать, чтобы ещё этакого дописать... затем решаешь дописать первое, что придёт в голову, а потом просто не можешь остановиться... И вот ты уже написал половину от максимального количества символов, но тебе всё ещё интересно, сможешь ли ты дойти до максимума, не начав повторяться или просто нести абстрактный псевдофилософский бред про странное устройство мироздания. И вот, когда ты уже всё написал, последнее предложение оказывается слишком длинным и приход...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Начинается ломка без со)

Comment: "почти все его перспективные применения уже покрыты constexpr" - покрыты во многом потому, что в С++17 `constexpr` автоматически подразумевает `inline`.

Comment: @AnT, `constexpr` (для переменных) всё же появился раньше и прекрасно справлялся с задачами без такой сущности как `inline`...

Answer (score 7):

Не-const переменная, объявленная на уровне пространства имен без слова `static` имеет *внешнее* связывание, т.е. существует в единственном экземпляре во всей программе.

Переменная, объявленная на уровне пространства имен со словом `static` имеет *внутреннее* связывание, т.е. существует как отдельная переменная в каждой единице трансляции, в которой объявлена.

Так было всегда.

---

`inline` никак не меняет этих свойств. `inline` лишь позволяет нам делать *множественные определения* переменных с внешним связыванием в разных единицах трансляции, не вызывая при этом нарушения ODR (полностью аналогично тому, как `inline` влияет на функции). Без `inline` нам придется идти по традиционному пути: помещать в заголовочные файлы extern-объявления глобальных переменных, а определения с инициализаторами прятать в файлах реализации. Это более громоздко и это приводит к тому, что инициализатор глобальной переменной виден лишь в одной единице трансляции. С `inline` все сводится к одному-единственному объявлению-определению, которое можно делать в заголовочном файле и которое целиком (т.е. вместе с инициализатором) видно везде.

Это в частности означает, что для переменных комбинация `inline static` является избыточной: можно просто написать `static` с тем же эффектом.

Comment: С каждым таким нововведением я задаю вопросы: когда С++ станет более медленным, чем Java, и зачем корячить в каждый стандарт столько мусора. С 1 стороны пытаются насытить фичами, а с другой - я уверен, что большинство не будет использовать всех фич - ибо слишком много и пока изучишь 1 стандарт - выйдет ещё 2.

Comment: Хм.. Что-то у вас двоих ответы противоположные. Можно какое-то подтверждение?

Comment: Хм, cpprefrence говорит немного другое.

Comment: @Ljil 1. Никогда, потому что скорость никак не связана с предоставляемыми языком возможностями. 2. Покажите более-менее сложный предмет хотя бы в домашнем обиходе, который вы используете на 100% :) И еще - цитирую Страуструпа: *You don’t have to know every detail of C++ to write good programs.*

Comment: @AnT, вроде разобрались.

Comment: @Ljil: В данном случае речь идет о возможностях времени компиляции, никак не влияющих на производительность генерируемого кода. Или вы ведете речь о скорости компиляции? Но эта фича не привносит ничего нового - она лишь вводит единообразие в линковке переменных и функций.